# Logistic discrete equation: analitic solution

Tags: trigonometry, discrete-optimization, logistic-regression

I have to proof that the solution for the logistic discrete equation: $x_{n+1}=4x_n\left(1-x_n\right)$ with $r=4$, and $x_0 \in (0,1)$ when $n=0$, it's of the form $$x_n=\sin^2\left(\beta\alpha^n\right)$$ and find the values of $\beta, \alpha$. With the following identities: $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$; $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$

So far I know that: $$ x_1 = 4x_0(1-x_0) $$
\begin{align*}
        x_2 & = 4x_1(1-x_1) \\
         & = 4(4x_0(1-x_0))(1-(4x_0(1-x_0))) \\
         & = 4^2x_0(1-x_0)(1-4x_0+4x_0^2) \\
         & = 4^2x_0(1-x_0)(1-2x_0)^2
    \end{align*}
$$ \vdots $$
and with the identities I have:  $\sin^2(2\theta) = 4\sin^2\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)$.

From that I know that $\alpha =2$, and I read in an article that $\beta = \sin^2(x_0)$. But I don't know what's the next step in the proof, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Just let $n=0$ in the equation $x_n=\sin^2(\beta\alpha^n)$

Comment: You still there, Vocado?